# Cairo with pdf support

Tags: linux, gtk, cairo, poppler

I'm compiling GTK+ manually as it requires Cairo with pdf support I installed poppler-glib but even after that in configure script of cairo I get:

```
checking for cairo's PDF surface backend feature...
checking whether cairo's PDF surface backend feature could be enabled... yes
checking for POPPLER... yes
checking for poppler_page_render... no
configure: WARNING: PDF backend will not be tested since poppler >= 0.17.4 is not available
```

I installed poppler-glib using `apt-get libpoppler-glib-dev` . Any help?

Comment: What version does `pkg-config --modversion poppler-glib` return?

Comment: I should add I often compile GTK+ (either 2 and 3) without PDF support in cairo and it works flawlessly, at least up to 3.14.10.

Comment: GTK is `3.16.2` and output of `pkg-config --modversion poppler-glib` is `0.18.4`

Comment: just compiled `3.10.2` same error

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong: I build cairo with PDF enabled but without poppler. The above message is a warning, not an error, so it should not prevent you from building cairo.

Comment: @ntd yes it will build cairo but without pdf support, but gtk requires cairo with pdf support

Comment: Did you try? According to the warning the PDF backend will not be tested, nothing is said about the build. And I build GTK+ without poppler all the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76620/discussion-between-nitin-kumar-and-ntd).

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded poppler from http://poppler.freedesktop.org/releases.html

configure, make & make install and finally cairo build with pdf support.

Still don't know why apt-get wasn't able to do that.